# How can Hadjicostas's formula be used to prove the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$?

Tags: integration, irrational-numbers, riemann-zeta

Hadjicostas's formula relates the $\Gamma$ and $\zeta$ functions with a special double integral:

$$
\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}{\frac {1-x}{1-xy}}(-\log(xy))^{s}\,dx\,dy=\Gamma (s+2)\left(\zeta (s+2)-{\frac {1}{s+1}}\right),
$$

for $\Re(s)>-2$ and $s\neq-1$. Plugging in $s=1$ yields the special value

$$
\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}{\frac {1-x}{1-xy}}(-\log(xy))\,dx\,dy=2\zeta(3)-1,
$$

which resembles the double integral used in Beukers' proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$:

$$
\int _{{0}}^{{1}}\int _{{0}}^{{1}}{\frac  {-\log(xy)}{1-xy}}{\tilde  {P_{{n}}}}(x){\tilde  {P_{{n}}}}(y)dxdy,
$$

where ${\tilde  {P_{{n}}}}(x)$ are shifted Legendre polynomials.

> Is it possible to conclude the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ solely based on 
>   $$
> \int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}{\frac {1-x}{1-xy}}(-\log(xy))\,dx\,dy=2\zeta(3)-1?
> $$

Comment: I highly doubt it, but of course it would be hard for me to say "no"

Comment: Have you tried to use Beukers' proof to see whether you can push it through from your integral?

Comment: @Klangen: have you noticed there is $n$ in one integral and not in the other? To prove irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ you have to find out a sequence of rational numbers converging to $\zeta(3)$. Sorry to ask this, but what do you plan to use as sequence?

Comment: Care to engage with the comments, Klangen?

Comment: Hi all, sorry I was out on the weekend. Thanks for your comments. Indeed, I made no attempt to ''adapt'' Beukers' proof around my integral. I thought perhaps this was something that has already been done before, but it seems not to be the case.